# Inaccesible due to protection level

Tags: vb.net

First of all, thanks in advance for helping. I've faced with a problem which states " 'con' is not declared.It may be inaccesible due to its protection level. I cant figure out what the main problem is. If you can help me to solve this problem, I'll be very happy.

```
    Private Function KayitVarmi(ByVal T_SayacNo As String, ByVal SayacAciklama As
    String) As BooleanDim 

    PnlTemp As New Panel
    KayitVarmi = True = False

    kayitSiraNo = 1

    For Each con As Control In PanelAna.Controls
        If TypeOf con Is Panel Then
            If Mid(con.Name, 1, 3) = "Pnl" Then
                If T_SayacNo = Mid(con.Name, 4, 8) Then
                    'SQL_Data_Al()
                    con.BackgroundImage = Panel8.BackgroundImage
                    KayitVarmi = True
                Else
                    con.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.KKK
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: On which line you have this error message?

Comment: Where is this `PanelAna` defined?

Comment: Problem states directly Mid(con.name,1,3), i.e, where con.(tag) exists

Comment: PanelAna is defined at another form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'con' is not declared.It may be inaccesible due to its protection
>   level.

`con` in this case is an instance of `Control` which is obtain from the collection `PanelAna.Controls`. You are iterating that collection, each iteration will get you a new instance.

Its possible that your class is not matching the class name in the **designer file**, could be in a different form? This causes it to interpreted as two separate classes, which causes the errors. The code in the one file is not able to reference objects defined in the other file.

**Note:** On VS2012 to access the designer file code, go to `Solution Explorer` on the top, click on the icon with two documents next to each other (show all files), then expand the Form.vb to see Designer code.

**Example**

```
'Panel1
'
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
Me.Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(40, 28)
Me.Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
Me.Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(200, 100)
Me.Panel1.TabIndex = 0
```